# Why isn't there a Bujinkan tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Bujinkan (?) seems to be a martial art that appears in different flavors with regularity. Is there a reason why there is not a tag for it? Is Bujinkan already a subset of an existing tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit of crossover with `ninjutsu`. I'm not certain how much we break away specific styles, especially since I suspect many people don't even differentiate. I would have no problem with it as a tag. We probably have about a dozen questions relating to it, and we have some subject-matter experts on the topic.

As regards the question in the comments about how exactly it fits in as a style, I'll be honest that I think it's somewhere in between a branch (like how we have a `Shotokan` tag to distinguish from `karate`) and marketing (my understanding is that you can't represent yourself as a Bujinkan school without being part of the organization, unlike, say, "Gracie Jiu-Jutsu" where the feuds between family branches have left the trademarks in dispute, or the broader "Brazilian Jiu-Jutsu" where there's even less restriction).

Lastly, while the Bujinkan system is typically thought of as a "Ninjutsu" school, only three of nine traditions of the school are claimed to be from ninja training, with the other six being from samurai training, so I think there's a good argument for it being supported as its own system, and tag, much like the various hybrid styles like Systema.

Comment: I don't know much about it myself, particularly what constitutes a Bujinkan style.

Comment: @mattm: Ah, I took some classes, not an expert. It's somewhere in between a branch (like `shotokan` is to `karate`) and marketing (I think you have to be part of the organization to use the branding, unlike Gracie BJJ where they lost that trademark suit). I think it's a fine tag to add. Not going to add a ton of traffic to the site, but very little does... :-(